# Receiving "The name {ProjectNamespace} does not exist in the current context" when trying to include namespace

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, .net-client-profile

I have three projects:

1. `TestNHibernateMappings` - A console project
2. `WebApplicationPbiBoard` - An Asp.Net MVC 3 Web project
3. `WebApplicationPbiBoard.Tests` - An MsTest project

`TestNHibernateMappings` needs a reference to the `PbiMap` class located in `WebApplicationPbiBoard.Models.ScrumModels_Mappings`.

I've added `WebApplicationPbiBoard` as a project reference to `TestNHibernateMappings`, but Visual Studio keeps giving me namespace non-existence error when I try to include it. I've also tried removing and re-adding the reference, and performing a clean build of the entire solution both with no luck.

Any idea how to fix this? I've tried teaching my project about Descartes and disabling the Solipsist=true flag in the Console App, but those didn't work out either. Thanks in advance.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.Database("WebApplicationPbiBoard");
    builder.Server("local");
    builder.TrustedConnection();

    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(builder.ToString()))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<WebApplicationPbiBoard.Models.ScrumModels_Mappings.PbiMap>())
        .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The `Fluently.Configure()...` part is my attempt to configure a FluentNHibernate Session.

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the target framework for `TestNHibernateMappings` and set it to .NET Framework 4.0. I suspect that you currently have it set to .NET Framework 4.0 **Client Profile** and that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem exactly. Do you have any insight as to why the Client Profile framework couldn't find the assembly?

Comment: @Vish: Because `TestNHibernateMappings` presumably relies on NHibernate and/or Fluent NHibernate which rely on components of the .NET Framework that are not in the .NET Framework Client Profile.